# Modulus of continuity example

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

could help me clear something out. I am looking for an example of modulus of continiuity. I was told that is doable  for: $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\in [0,1]$.
Some calc:
From definition:$|f(x)-f(y)|=\sqrt{(f(x)-f(y))^2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-y^2})^2}=\sqrt{y^2-x^2-2\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}}\le \omega(|x-y|)=\omega(\sqrt{x^2-y^2-2xy}))$

How from that I can choose $\omega$?

Comment: Picture the graph. It gets steeper and steeper. so $\omega(\delta) = f(1-\delta) - f(1)$.

Comment: Ok. That's clever. f(1)=0, so it's enough $\omega(x)=f(1-x)$. Thanks!